# How to setup DHCP only on the wireless side of a router or AP?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, dhcp, wireless-access-point

We are currently running a simple network with unmanaged switches.  We already have a Internet feed with router and DHCP.  Im looking to add in another separate internet feed, with a 2nd router (NO DHCP on it and competely separate IP Schema) and hard code a wireless access point back to the 2nd router.  But would like DHCP to feed out only on the wireless side, without it flooding back up stream on the hard wired network lines and interfering with the current primary DHCP.  All of the above devices would exist on the same physical (again unmanaged switches) network.

Is this possible?  Any model or devices suggested?   The why of all of this is convoluted!

Answer (score 0):

If you want DHCP only on the wireless side, configure the systems that you don't want to use DHCP with to assign static ip. Be careful, as those IPs mustn't be in the DHCP IP range. That's why you should shrink the IP range of the DHCP(this can be done from your router setings) so you will have enough free IPs for your other computers. You must configure them to asign a static IP, and choose one from the remained IPs after you shrank the DHCP IP range.

Hope it helps.